# Lucene.Net PrefixQuery

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I´m development a suggest box for my site search service. I has to search fields like these:

Visual Basic Enterprise Edition
Visual C++
Visual J++

My code is:

```
  Directory dir = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.GetDirectory("Index", false);

  IndexSearcher searcher = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher( dir,true);    

  Term term = new Term("nombreAnalizado", _que);

  PrefixQuery query = new PrefixQuery(term);

  TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query, 10000);
```

This code works well in this case:

"Enterprise" will match "Visual Basic Enterprise Edition"

But "Enterprise E" doesn´t match anything.

I removed white spaces at indexing time and when the user is searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the QueryParser and let it build the appropriate Query object instead of using something specific like the PrefixQuery.

In Java:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "nombreAnalizado", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT));
Query query = parser.parse(_que);
```

Make sure you are using the same analyzer that you used for indexing.